# Should a stack object be comparable

Tags: java, data-structures, stack, comparable

I am currently attempting to implement a stack in Java and I am wondering if it makes sense to have a stack implement Comparable and how I would go about doing that. Also, while I'm on the topic, my stack is cloneable which makes sense in my opinion but I'd like to see what other people think about that as well. Thanks.

Comment: This is really too broad of a question for Stackoverflow (and you want to keep your questions to one question per question).  If you make a `Stack<Comparable>` and run into trouble at some point, then we can help you.  (But are you comparing the stack to another stack, or comparing elements of the stack?)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it